# How to get the title for a UIButton when it is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I'm trying to discover what the UIButton title is for which UIButton was pressed in the following code.

on viewDidLoad the button title is outputted to the console using:

```
        NSLog(@"The button title is %@ ", btn.titleLabel.text);
```

I would like to get this title when a button is pressed instead.

thanks for any help

:)

```
// Create buttons for the sliding category menu.
        NSMutableArray* buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSArray * myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category-cafe-unsel.png", @"category-food-unsel.png", @"category-clothing-unsel.png", @"category-health-unsel.png", @"category-tech-unsel_phone.png" , @"category-tech2-unsel.png", @"catefory-theatre-unsel.png", @"category-travel-unsel.png", nil];

        // only create the amount of buttons based on the image array count
        for(int i = 0;i < [myImages count]; i++)
        {
            // Custom UIButton

            btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 52.0f, 52.0f)];
            [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSLog(@"The button title is %@ ", btn.titleLabel.text);

            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [buttonArray addObject:btn];

            NSLog(@"Button tag is: %d",btn.tag);

        }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your action:

```
- (void) buttonPressed:(UIButton*) sender {
    NSLog(@"The button title is %@",sender.titleLabel.text);
}
```

**Edit**:
Or as commented Iulian: `sender.currentTitle`, but it may be `nil`, see the comments of Michael.

Comment: What's the difference between this and `sender.currentTitle`?

Comment: I didn't say that it isn't, I was just asking. And just now `currentTitle` was `nil` but `titleLabel.text` wasn't.

Comment: This got me to thinking and I checked with the docs. The first answer, which I prefer, gets the label object (that's why I like it), then the text property. The second, currentTitle, is state-specific and may be nil. From the docs r.e. currentTitle: The value for this property is set automatically whenever the button state changes. For states that do not have a custom title string associated with them, this method returns the title that is currently displayed, which is typically the one associated with the UIControlStateNormal state. The value may be nil.

Comment: @MichaelOlenick, I read that too after posting the comment, but it's still odd, If the `titleLabel.text` is not nil, that means that the button has a text set _(so is the situation in my case)_, so shouldn't `currentTitle` return the same text?

Comment: Yeah - seems like it shouldn't be nil in your example. I rarely use the button state's: instead I make them disappear if they're inactive. Otherwise inexperienced users can tap away or become frustrated trying to figure out how to activate them.

Answer (score 11):

You should have the function somewhere...

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
```

Just put this inside it...

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *someButton = (UIButton*)sender;

    NSLog(@"The button title is %@ ", [someButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]);

    //You should also be able to use...
    //NSLog(@"The button title is %@ ", someButton.titleLabel.text);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString * strButtonTitle = [btnButton titleForState:state];
```

where state:

```
UIControlStateNormal,
UIControlStateHighlighted,
UIControlStateDisabled,
UIControlStateSelected,
UIControlStateFocused,
UIControlStateApplication,
UIControlStateReserved
```

For your requirement

```
NSString * strButtonTitle = [btnButton titleForState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

This is the method for getting the title for different states of button at any given time in the program...But based on the question answer from **Zaphod** is good.