# Get value from Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I had made dropdown list of items. The list opens when i click the button and value appear on that button now i want that value to store in a string. I'm trying it with `NSString *button=[Country text];` but it is displaying error.

Comment: what error, u r facing?, need more detail

Comment: What is `Country`?

Comment: Country is name of button on which when click it open list of countries and after selection the name comes of that country on that button. now i want that value in a variable to display through NSlog. @iphonic

Comment: Check below link  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38116326/5184217

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want get title from Button

```
NSString *button = [[Country titleLabel] text];
```

Comment: i have submit button when the value is stored in a string than i have to click the submit button then it should display value. As per ur answer the value is displaying but when i select the item it got displayed. I want it to display when i click submit button. @Luan Tran

Answer (score 0):

just a line of code:

```
NSString *reciever = Country.titleLabel.text
```